# Google Chrome's icon after Ubuntu 14.10 lastest update

Tags: unity, google-chrome, icons

I am getting the gray box with a question mark in the middle of the icon for chrome, before it would show the chrome icon but now it's this ugly icon, I did fix it with a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-stable` and the icon came back, but it goes back to the gray box icon after a reboot.

Is there a permanent fix for this?

Edit: seems installing Google Chrome Beta or Unstable fixes Google Chromes Stable's icon to  normal, will reboot after unstable installes

[image]

Comment: Hi Kyle, I noticed you practically never accepted an answer on your questions. That could be because the answer(s) simply didn't work, but also because you simply "forget". It is a useful however to make clear an answer works by accepting it. If my answer worked for you, would you consider accepting it?

Answer (score 6):

Google Chrome is famous for producing local `.desktop` files (launchers) in `~/.local/share/applications`. The downside is that these `.desktop` files are not updated when the application is updated. Appearantly the latest update makes earlier `.desktop` files incompatible.

#### What to do

Navigate to `~/.local/share/applications`, find and delete all launchers, related to `Google Chrome`, log out and back in. It should be fixed then.

Comment: Marking them as `allow executing` will mean you can see the icons. Their names are indescriptive: `anlmfdlplepcaeifjippdehbmocbckmd`.  Also, press Alt+F2 and type `r` to restart X, rather than logging out.

Comment: True, but in my experience `Google Chrome` gives away its identity in the `.desktop` files' name(s). I used log out/in for its " understanability"  for average users.

Answer (score 0):

Your chrome extensions can cause this problem.

For example, my extension "Multiple Accounts for Outlook" causes this problem if enable "Shortcut On Apps Menu" in extension settings.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to solve this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score -2):

I would lurk around the install directory where Chromium is (probably somewhere is /usr/) and see if you find any .png, .bmp, or .jpg files (or just images in general).  You may be able to manually deny deletion to it like this:

```
sudo chmod 644 [name]
sudo chown root:root [name]
```

That should prevent deletion, unless for some reason it's deleting it as root.

Comment: That's not where icons are stored on ubuntu. You're looking for `/usr/share/icons/Humanity`.

Comment: well, after about three to four chrome restarts, open and closing it, the icon shows up.
that a major bug?

Comment: I meant recursively in /usr/

Comment: I found the fault, I have folders of my programs in folder by Unity Launcher Folders. Apparently, if I launch Google Chrome from the dock folder created by Unity Launcher Folders then I will get the grey question mark icon but if I launch it from the Dash, I get an icon. that's a weird bug.